# I'm at my wits end to make my ESP32 capture keypresses and send it over serial. Any tips?

Tags: arduino, keyboard, serial-port, esp32

This is the code.

```
#include <Arduino.h>

const int numRows = 4;
const int numCols = 12;

const byte rowPins[numRows] = {1, 3, 17, 4};
const byte colPins[numCols] = {16, 0, 2, 15, 13, 12, 14, 27, 26, 25, 33, 32};

char keyMap[numRows][numCols] = {
  {'1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0', '-', '='},
  {'Q', 'W', 'E', 'R', 'T', 'Y', 'U', 'I', 'O', 'P', '[', ']'},
  {'A', 'S', 'D', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'J', 'K', 'L', ';', '\'', '\\'},
  {'Z', 'X', 'C', 'V', 'B', 'N', 'M', ',', '.', '/', ' ', ' '}
};

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);

  for (int i = 0; i < numRows; i++) {
    pinMode(rowPins[i], INPUT_PULLUP);
  }

  for (int j = 0; j < numCols; j++) {
    pinMode(colPins[j], OUTPUT);
    digitalWrite(colPins[j], HIGH);
  }
}

void loop() {
  for (int col = 0; col < numCols; col++) {
    digitalWrite(colPins[col], LOW); // Activate the current column
    for (int row = 0; row < numRows; row++) {
      if (digitalRead(rowPins[row]) == LOW) {
        char key = keyMap[row][col];
        if (key != ' ') { // Ignore empty spaces
          Serial.print(key); // Send the captured key to the serial console
        }
        delay(50); // Debounce delay
      }
    }
    digitalWrite(colPins[col], HIGH); // Deactivate the column
  }
}
```

It connects, but doesn't detect any keypresses (or at least doesn't send it over the serial monitor.

Any ideas?

This is a Wroom 32 ESP32 with 38 pins.

I tried changing the logic from row to col > col to row. I tried changing the baud rates. I uploaded a simple program to count from 0 to 100 to make sure the board is functional and the serial monitor works.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are trying to make something like a "membrane keyboard" but with push buttons.

Depending on the type of buttons/switches that you are using (normally open or normally closed) you may need to invert or generally mess around with the LOW/HIGH on the outputs.

At the moment you are getting the power juice to flow to the buttons in the setup() (HIGH = power on) and killing it in the loop, I have a feeling that should be the other way around. Are your buttons correctly connected to the ground?